# Disable dragging of polyline while allowing other layer to drag in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am creating map overlaying multiple png file using Leaflet.js.
I want to overlay polyline on top of these map disabling polyline to move.
The behavior I expect is following.
User can drag the map which is composed by png file. While map is being dragged, polyline doesn't move.
How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the polyline

```
var polyline = L.polyline(...);
```

Then you can use

```
map.addLayer(polyline);//For show
map.removeLayer(polyline);// For hide
```

at the moment I think there is no native method to only hide/show, maybe in the 0.7 version

Other solution is to access to the object container, in a old commet from the maintainer

```
I don't think there's an easy solution, for tile layers at least. :( I'll try to handle this sooner.
For vectors, you can change path._container.style.display, and for markers - marker._image.style.display and marker._shadow.style.display.
```